# Selecting max and sum over period

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a hash of temperatures that's collected every 30 minutes. I want to group by day and select the max temperature for that day, then add the max temperature over the seven days.

The code below seems to only select the max temperature for the 7 days and does not sum the max temperature for each day.

**Data is collected via JSON**

```
{"status": "ok", "data": [{"temperature": 22.4, "date": "20160815-1430"}, {"temperature": 20.4, "date": "20160815-1500"}}
```

**Then in my controller**

```
@data['data'].each do |d|
  rainTotal << [DateTime.parse(d['date']), d['temperature']]
end

@rainTotal = rainTotal.group_by{ |h| h[0] }.reject{ |k, v| !( ((7.day.ago.to_date)..(Date.now)) === k ) }.inject(0){ |sum, h| sum + h.second.max_by { |h| h[1] }[1].to_f }
```

Comment: that's one long line of logic to have in a controller.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant to your issue, but why is your controller looking for fields of `tslocal` and `rain` when the data has fields of `date` and `temperature`?

Comment: Thanks Max, forgot to update the code. Have fixed those fields to reflect my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `rainTotal.group_by{ |h| h[0] }`, you're grouping by the `DateTime` object. If every date/time combination is unique, the result is that there will be essentially no grouping, and you'll just get a sum across all of the temperatures.

Changing that part to `rainTotal.group_by{ |h| h[0].to_date }` should fix that particular issue.

Comment: Ahhh, nailed it. Cheers @Max.